# How to convert TIMESTAMP values to VARCHAR in T-SQL as SSMS does?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, nvarchar, sql-timestamp

I am trying to convert a TIMESTAMP field in a table to a string so that it can be printed or executed as part of dynamic SQL. SSMS is able to do it, so there must be a built-in method to do it. However, I can't get it to work using T-SQL.

The following correctly displays a table result:

```
SELECT TOP 1 RowVersion FROM MyTable
```

It shows `0x00000000288D17AE`. However, I need the result to be part of a larger string.

```
DECLARE @res VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 'test' + CONVERT(BINARY(8), RowVersion) FROM MyTable)
PRINT(@res)
```

This yields an error: `The data types varchar and binary are incompatible in the add operator`

```
DECLARE @res VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 'test' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), RowVersion) FROM MyTable)
PRINT(@res)
```

This results in garbage characters: `test    (®`

In fact, the spaces are just null characters and terminate the string for the purpose of running dynamic SQL using `EXEC()`.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT TOP 1 ''test'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), RowVersion) FROM MyTable'
EXEC (@sql)
```

This just displays a table result with the word "test". Everything after "test" in the dynamic SQL is cut off because the `CONVERT` function returns terminating null characters first.

Obviously, what I want the resultant string to be is "test0x00000000288D17AE" or even the decimal equivalent, which in this case would be "test680335278".

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SSMS doesn't do any such conversion. It displays data in a grid just like *any* other .NET application. Binary values are typically shown as hex or Base64. Why do you want to convert a binary value to a string at all? Why not pass it as is, or use it as a parameter? BTW `rowversion` can't be used as an identifier either, if you thought you can use it as a human-readable key

Comment: A [rowversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) is a `binary(8)` value, just like `bigint`. You can cast it to bigint then use [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(format_TSQL);k(sql13.swb.tsqlresults.f1);k(sql13.swb.tsqlquery.f1);k(MiscellaneousFilesProject);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) to get its hex representation, eg `FORMAT(cast(RowVersion)as bigint),"x")` or `FORMAT(cast(cast(RowVersion as binary(8))as bigint),"x")`. Format won't pad the string with zeros though

Comment: While it's undocumented, I believe `master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr` will convert any `VARBINARY` type value to an `NVARCHAR` value. See [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1708985.aspx) for some info on how this function works, along with source code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`SELECT 'test' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(BINARY(8), RowVersion), 1)`. The trick is the `1` to the `CONVERT` as the style, per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187928). (Pass `2` to omit the `0x`.)

Comment: Have you tried this? It returns `Explicit conversion from data type timestamp to nvarchar(max) is not allowed`. If I change it to `VARCHAR`, there's no error, but it still shows garbage as described in the Question.

Comment: @Neo: My bad, I incorrectly assumed SQL Server would treat `ROWVERSION` as a binary type. It does not, so an intermediate conversion step is necessary to make that work.

Comment: The accepted Answer is the best solution I think. `SELECT TOP 1 'test' + master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(RowVersion) FROM MyTable` gets me exactly what I need.

Comment: @Neo: relying on undocumented functions is demonstrably worse than relying on the built-in functionality of `CONVERT`. What you accept is up to you, of course, but I know what I'd prefer in a production environment.

Comment: @Neo have you tried the edited version of [Jeroen Mostert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert)'s solution? It works for me with the additional step of `CONVERT`ing to `BINARY(8)` first, before then `CONVERT`ing to `NVARCHAR`... As such, and for the reasons given above by Jeroen, I have upvoted this answer as I believe it's better than my own.

Comment: OK, my bad this time. Yes, the edited version works. In fact, I now prefer this answer as the hex letters remain upper case (looks nicer). It's not production code (it's just a script to help me in dev), but I prefer doing things the most proper way, and I think this is it. I'll change the accepted Answer to this one, but still upvote your one, @3N1GM4. Thanks for the honesty!

Comment: @Neo no problem, always happy to admit when someone has a better answer than me!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, the undocumented function `master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr` will convert binary to string such that you could then concatenate with some other string value:

```
DECLARE @binary BINARY(8)
SELECT @binary = CAST(1234567890 AS BINARY(8))

SELECT @binary AS BinaryValue, 
       LEFT(master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@binary),2) + UPPER(RIGHT(master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@binary),LEN(master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@binary))-2)) AS VarcharValue,
       'test' + LEFT(master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@binary),2) + UPPER(RIGHT(master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@binary),LEN(master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@binary))-2)) AS ConcatenatedVarcharValue
```

I went ahead and split the first two characters and did not apply the `UPPER` function to them, to exactly reproduce the format as displayed when a binary value.

Results:

```
/--------------------------------------------------------------------\
|     BinaryValue    |    VarcharValue    | ConcatenatedVarcharValue |
|--------------------+--------------------+--------------------------|
| 0x00000000499602D2 | 0x00000000499602D2 |  test0x00000000499602D2  |
\--------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

Comment: Thanks. `SELECT TOP 1 'test' + master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(RowVersion) FROM MyTable` gets me exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this:

```
SELECT 
substring(replace(replace(replace(replace(cast(CAST(GETDATE() AS datetime2) as 
varchar(50)),'-',''),' ',''),':',''),'.',''),1,18)
```

Comment: Add an explanation to the answer as to why it works.